# Repeat header and footer on every pdf page with Jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 together with python, psycopg2 and pdfkit to create a pdf file depending on different variables.

I have a specific header and footer that should be placed on **every page** (like a logo, the page numbers and other similar items). I used `<div style="display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;"></div>` to add a page break (working nice).

I really would avoid to repeat html code block in my template.html (so for every page). Is there a Jinja way to define this?

This is a piece of the template.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../templates/mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="../img/logo.png">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>The number is {{ query_dict.num_n }}</li>
    </ul>

    <table class="center">
    <!-- <table width=680 border=1 cellpadding=20 cellspacing=0> -->
        <tr>
            <th>Type of </th>
            <th>{{ query_dict.type }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Variable width</th>
            <th>{{ query_dict.width }}</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- page break -->
    <div style="display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;"></div>

    <img src="../img/my_img.png">

    <!-- page break -->
    <div style="display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;"></div>

    <p>other content</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to create your header/footer on a separate html-page and use one of the two options of jinja2 to repeat this page on your main html page. This way you had only include a simple statement on every pagebreak.

Those would be [Include](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#include) or the use of child-templates through [Inheritance](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-inheritance).

With in include:

template.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../templates/mystyle.css">
</head>

<p>Content<p>

{% include 'myFooter.html' %}
```

myFooter.html:

```
 <div id="footer">
 &copy; Copyright 2020 by <a href = "mailto: yourmail@mail.com">YourName</a>.
 </div>
 <img src="../img/logo.png">
<!-- page break -->
<div style="display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;"></div>
```

In this simple example you would include the footer after the content and insert automatically mailto,img and a break at this point. Variables are passed to your included html-page by default from your calling html.

If you use jinja2 inheritance you can define this equaly and just fill predifined blocks on your main template. The important part is to mark a file to extend your main file `{% extends "myIndex.html" %}`.

With inheritance:

template.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../templates/mystyle.css">
</head>

<p>Content<p>

<div id="content">{% block footerContent %}{% endblock %}</div>
```

footerChild.html

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block footerContent %}
<div id="footer">
&copy; Copyright 2020 by <a href = "mailto: yourmail@mail.com">YourName</a>.
</div>
<img src="../img/logo.png">
<!-- page break -->
<div style="display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Of course you could include them into loops or [if-statement](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if)s to meet the conditions of your page.